# Cookie is changed on every request, using sinatra and Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie

Tags: ruby, cookies, sinatra, session-cookies, rack

I'm new to web app development & have just started learning Sinatra framework. I'm currently developing a login system.
Here's the necessary code :

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'openssl'
require 'encrypted_cookie'

configure do
  use Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie, :secret => "foo-bar-baz", :httponly => true
```

Then, I'm storing username in the session if he/she is authorized :

```
post '/' do
  if authorize(params[:name], params[:password], params[:csrfkey])
    session[:name] = params[:name]
  end
end
```

The cookie is encrypted all right. And it is also remembering session values.

But while using Firebug I noticed that at every request(page load, refresh, etc) the cookie's content is changed & I mean completely changed. It seems like Sinatra is sending new cookie at every request.

Previously, I was using `enable :sessions` & the cookie never changed.

So my questions are, is it normal to have cookie's content changed at every request while in a session?

Is it happening because it is encrypted?

I searched high & low on the net but no one has got this problem I guess..

Comment: Yes this is normal, and may in fact protect against some kinds of session hijacking attacks, but I don't know what `Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie` is doing specifically, so cannot provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Ohh, ok. I'm just curious to know why the cookie's content is changing even though the session content isn't changing at all. Thank you for your reply. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [source for encrypted_cookie](https://github.com/cvonkleist/encrypted_cookie/blob/master/lib/encrypted_cookie.rb) shows that it [generates different encrypted output every time it is called regardless of the input](https://github.com/cvonkleist/encrypted_cookie/blob/master/lib/encrypted_cookie.rb#L73). There are 2 reasons for this:

- **The *library* would have to know what the session value was during the last request.** It doesn't, all it does is accept a single input, the given session. If you wished to circumvent this and just rewrite the cookie (I suppose) you could, since you have the extra information available higher up in the Sinatra app.
- **It's more secure.** It doesn't leak information (if the cookie doesn't change then an observer of the cookie knows nothing changed during the request), and it gives an attacker less time to try and get to a meaningful value.

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation! I'll upvote the answer but dont have enough repv right now.

Comment: @Rahul no problem, glad I could be of help.